# Joda PrintZeroRarelyFirst not working

Tags: java, jodatime

I'm trying to have Joda print "0 seconds" if the input time is zero, but instead its just printing nothing at all.

The below example just outputs an empty string.  Whats going on here?

```
PeriodFormatter hoursMinutesSeconds = new PeriodFormatterBuilder()
    .appendHours().appendSuffix(" hour", " hours")
    .appendSeparator(", ", " and ")
    .appendMinutes()
    .appendSuffix(" minute", " minutes")
    .appendSeparator(" and ")
    .printZeroRarelyFirst()
    .appendSeconds()
    .appendSuffix(" second", " seconds")
    .toFormatter();

System.out.println(hoursMinutesSeconds.print(new Period(0, 0, 0, 500)));
```

Comment: It works with `printZeroRarelyLast()` though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need an early `printZeroAlways` and move your `printZeroRarelyFirst` up a bit to make it work to say `0 hours`.

```
import org.joda.time.Period;
import org.joda.time.format.PeriodFormatter;
import org.joda.time.format.PeriodFormatterBuilder;

public class TestFormat {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    PeriodFormatter hoursMinutesSeconds = new PeriodFormatterBuilder()
    .printZeroAlways()
    .appendHours().appendSuffix(" hour", " hours")
    .printZeroRarelyFirst()
    .appendSeparator(", ", " and ")
    .appendMinutes()
    .appendSuffix(" minute", " minutes")
    .appendSeparator(" and ")
    .appendSeconds()
    .appendSuffix(" second", " seconds")
    .toFormatter();
     System.out.println(hoursMinutesSeconds.print(new Period(0, 0, 0, 0)));
  }
}
```

You might prefer the `printZeroRarelyLast` solution, though, because the method above always gives you the 0 hours.

I prefer

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    PeriodFormatter hoursMinutesSeconds = new PeriodFormatterBuilder()
    .printZeroRarelyLast()
    .appendHours().appendSuffix(" hour", " hours")
    .appendSeparator(", ", " and ")
    .appendMinutes()
    .appendSuffix(" minute", " minutes")
    .appendSeparator(" and ")
    .appendSeconds()
    .appendSuffix(" second", " seconds")
    .toFormatter();
     System.out.println(hoursMinutesSeconds.print(new Period(0, 0, 0, 0)));
}
```

Comment: Actually I want it to print "0 seconds", and I think I messed up the example a bit.  I'll edit it; it should be `new Period(0,0,0,500)`

Comment: Ah, now it is a good question.  You can always round your Period object to the nearest second (or generate a new Period object like your original but rounded to the nearest second) before passing it to that method.

Comment: Is there a function in Joda for that? Or do I just have to do `new Period(time / 1000 * 1000)`?  (My actual input in a long)

Comment: `new Period(whateverYourInputDataIs).withMillis(0)`

Comment: Ah ok, I figured there was a cleaner way of doing it.  Thanks